# Blank Output for Chinese Characters in LaTex

Tags: xetex, languages, xecjk

I have installed all the .sty packages that needed to type Chinese in LaTex, and I used the code below:

```
% UTF-8 encoding

% XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\begin{document}

文章内容

\end{document}
```

After typesetting, the PDF file came out black only with page numbers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get 文章内容